# How can I set a fetchLimit dynamically for a SwiftUI @FetchRequest?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, fetchrequest

I am using a FetchRequest in a chat app and want to set the fetchLimit dynamically.  First I want to load 50 messages, then an additional number when the user scrolls to the top of the chat message list.

I am using the following code:

```
@FetchRequest private var messages: FetchedResults<Message>

private var predicate: NSPredicate
private var fetchLimit = 50
    
init(chatID: String) {
    
    self.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chatID_ = %@", chatID)

    self._messages = FetchRequest(
        entity: Message.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Message.createdAt_, ascending: true),
        ],
        predicate: self.predicate
    )
}
```

How can I incorporate a fetchLimit into this which I can change dynamically?

Comment: I don’t think you can do that dynamically

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I guess I’ll have to add a date predicate after the object x offset. Which unfortunately means another query to get that object.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61632618/12299030?

Comment: Hi @Asperi. It does work very well.  It does give me the first 5 rather than the last 5 to preserve the sort order (chat app with most recent message on bottom).  That should be trivial to solve by reversing the iteration though.  Thanks so much.