# Dynamic sort descriptor FetchRequest SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm having trouble figuring out how to dynamically update Core Data's `FetchRequest`'s `NSSortDescriptor` in SwiftUI. I'm not sure if setting it in `.onAppear` is the correct way which it doesn't as I'm seeing a strange rearranging of my list. I'm using an `AppStorage` variable to store my sorting then I set the `NSSortDescriptor` `.onAppear`, and save when state changes. Also I detect any changes in my `Picker` selection and apply it to my `FetchRequest` configuration's sort descriptor like Apple describe's [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest/configuration). If I remove the `FetchRequest`'s animation I don't see the strange rearranging but I also don't get any animations which doesn't look nice. I'm really unsure how to solve this or if I'm even doing this right.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    // Set default sort descriptor as empty because it's set in onAppear
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default) // or set to .none
    private var items: FetchedResults<Entity>
    @AppStorage("sortby") var sortby: SortBy = .title
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    ForEach(sort.allCases) { sort in
                        Button(sort.title, action: {
                            sortby = sort
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            // When sort changes set the new value here
            .onChange(of: sortby, perform: { value in
                items.nsSortDescriptors =  //NSSortDescriptor here
            })
            // Set initial sort descriptor here
            .onAppear(perform: {
                items.nsSortDescriptors =  //NSSortDescriptor here
            })
        }
    }
}
```

`FetchRequest`'s animation is set to default and rearranging.

[image: animation sorting issue]

`FetchRequest`'s animation is set to none, it works but then no animations become available when sorting.

[image: sorting no animation]

Comment: Instead of setting it in onAppear your FetchRequest should have a default sort descriptor set.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I’ve set a default and it does the same rearranging.

Comment: Consider this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/61632618/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi I understand that yes but that won't resolve my issue.

Comment: You should set the sort descriptors in an init : as you do , you first have 1st fetch with no sort when the view is created, then a second fetch in onAppear, then a third one on change of sort. The first one can be avoided by setting the default sort with the one from app storage in init() if that is your problem.

Comment: @PtitXav that won't work in init(). Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View.

Comment: @cole I am currently facing the same problem you had. Have you please found a solution? I would be very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: @parapote I haven’t found a solution, I opted for static. It resets when the app is killed but works. I haven’t spent much more time on dynamic sorting