# How to fetch SectionedFetchRequest in a view with predicate that use variables not yet initialized?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have 2 important entities in CoreData: 1) generic products (`Item_general`) and 2) occurrence of a product, that user customized and put to his cart (`Repository_item`).

I want to display to the user list of products that user added, however it must be grouped by generic product and displayed all together in one view. Additionally, products must be filtered by category (`Item_category`) So I believe, I need to group results in a view using `SectionedFetchRequest`, and put the category as predicate.

This code below is part of the view and does not work because of error:

> Cannot use instance member 'itemCategorySet' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

```
@SectionedFetchRequest<Item_general,Repository_item>(
    sectionIdentifier: \Repository_item.item_occurrence!.item_general!,
    sortDescriptors: [],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "Repository_item.item_occurrence.item_general.item_category.guid = %@", itemCategorySet.guid!.description)
)
private var sectionedItems: SectionedFetchResults<Item_general,Repository_item>
var itemCategorySet: Item_category
```

So I tried a different approach and moved the query to persistence controller.
And this code below has error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'SectionedFetchRequest<Item_general, Repository_item>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest'"

```
func getItemGeneralByCategory(guid: UUID!) -> SectionedFetchResults<Item_general,Repository_item>.Element? {
    let fetchRequest = SectionedFetchRequest<Item_general,Repository_item>(sectionIdentifier: \Repository_item.item_occurrence!.item!, sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "item_occurrence.item.category.guid = %@,", guid.description))

    // Get a reference to a NSManagedObjectContext
    let context = container.viewContext
    if let objects = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
        return objects
    }
}
```

Is there a way to read the data directly in the view (first method)?

If not, how should I read data from SectionedFetchRequest in persistanceController?

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871088/swiftui-view-and-fetchrequest-predicate-with-variable-that-can-change

Comment: Great, thank you! it is building. I have to fix couple of other issues and will report here the final code.

Comment: It works quite similarly as with FetchRequest, I was amazed that you don't have to execute the query, but SwiftUI does it automatically. Just the declared type had to be `private var sectionedItems: SectionedFetchResults<Item_general,Repository_item>{sectionedFetchRequest.wrappedValue}`