# Dynamically filtering @FetchRequest with SwiftUI using EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Is there any way to create a FetchRequest using an EnvironmentOjbect as a NSPredicate? I read [this article by Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui), which is great, but I did not want to pass in the variable to the `init`. Instead I wanted to use an EnvrionmentObject. I tried the response starting with "Edit 9/10/2023" of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871088/swiftui-view-and-fetchrequest-predicate-with-variable-that-can-change), but it kept crashing.

I tried one of the responses in [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122426) (the one that starts with "After two years I have the solution"), with `onAppear` vs `onChange` but it didn't seem to use the NSPredicate or refresh the data.

```
@EnvironmentObject var myObject: MyObject
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)]) var scenarios: FetchedResults<Scenario>
```

...

```
.onAppear() {

   print("onAppear caseid: \(myObject.Uid)")
   scenarios.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "caseid == %@", myObject.Uid as CVarArg)
            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a func to set the predicate as the first thing in body, e.g.

```
func updatePredicate() {
    if scenarios.nsPredicate != nil { return }
    scenarios.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "caseid == %@", myObject.Uid as CVarArg)
}

var body: some View {
    let _ = updatePredicate()
    ...
}
```

This is acceptable because setting the predicate is not a state mutation.